# How to display holoviews table with many columns completely

Tags: python, holoviews, pyviz

I have some DataFrames with many columns. When I try to visualize them with holoviews.Table, only the first columns are displayed.

For test purposes I created a DataFrame with 50 columns.

```py
import pandas as pd
import panel as pn
import holoviews as hv
pn.extension()

df = pd.DataFrame({'1': [1]})
for i in list(range(2, 50)):
    df[str(i)] = [i]
df
```

[image]

The I tried to display the DataFrame as Table:

```py
table= hv.Table(df, label='displayed table is node wide enough')
pn.Row(table)
```

[image: table]

Is there some option / way to display the complete table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `width` is the solution:

```py
table.opts(width=1550)
pn.Row(table)
```

displays the table with the correct width to show all columns.